# KeyCharacterMap in Android?

Tags: android

Can i use InputManagerService for a Key handling in Android?
I need the KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER event in Android.

Is this possible using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use onKeyDown in Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "DPAD_CENTER button pressed");
        // implement your stuff here
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**EDIT:**

To programmatically invoke onKeyDown:

```
KeyEvent kevent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, kevent);
```

Comment: Actually i am not preesing the DPAD_CENTER in android. But i want to initiate the click programattically... Please help me!!